# Nivo slider: Some effects not working?

Tags: jquery, slider, transition, effect, nivo-slider

So i thought i'd implement the Nivo jQuery slider to one of my projects. Everything is implemented and it should work fine as far as i know, but for some reason some effects don't work.

If i set the animSpeed to less than 500 (the default value) even less effects work, and i either get a slide-in-from-right or i just get a static switch (it waits for the animSpeed to finish, then just switches the image). Also worth mentioning that the animSpeed is ignored for some transitions, it stays at at least 500 (even more perhaps) sometimes.

Code for firing the plugin:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
      effect: 'boxRandom',
      animSpeed: 500,
      pauseTime: 5*1000,
      directionNav: true,
      controlNav: false,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      prevText: 'Prev',
      nextText: 'Next',
      randomStart: true,
  });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <a href="#"> <img src="valid/source1.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="valid/source2.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="valid/source3.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="valid/source4.jpg" alt="" /> </a>
</div> <!-- slider-->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, I tried tweaking the JavaScript code with no success. Any help will be appeciated!

Comment: I ended up ditching Nivo and going with a much simpler variant, SlidesJS. Was having lots of issues with Nivo, i surely spent hours trying to fix it without any progress. Took me 10 minutes to get SlidesJS working just as i wanted.

Comment: thanks for the update, i'll certainly check it out.